# How to create scaled Bitmap according to the custom ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, libraries

Actually I want to set the bitmap to my ImageView according to the ImageView dimension and i have one more query , In my android application i used the TEN  3rd party libraries in my app so when i open the application it takes some time to load the first activity. so, is it possible it's caused by the libraries?

ImageVIew XML:

```
 <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/girl"
    android:src="@drawable/user"
    app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
    app:civ_border_width="4dp"
    app:civ_shadow="true"
    app:civ_shadow_radius="1"
    app:civ_shadow_color="#bdbdbd"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="119dp"
   />
```

Code:

```
Bitmap bitmap_j = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image_key");
      Bitmap scaledBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap_j,400,220,true);
```

Comment: ask your question clearly.

Comment: scale down the **bitmap_j** according to the imageView dimension( android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp")

Comment: you can use more libraries. there is no issues.

Comment: can u tell me Sir how can i create ScaledBitmap

Comment: have you tried android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: yes i tried but after that app crash problem is arise

Comment: what error? can you post the LOGCAT error with your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130081/discussion-between-techdigi-and-user3026347).

Comment: ScaleType FIT_XY not supported in my thrid party library